# ListFragment is not refreshing after adding data from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-listfragment

I am trying to update my list after getting data, but when I tried, nothing happens and the same old data is still displayed. I have tried getting the data asynchronously, but the same issue occurred.
Here's the code.

```
public class myFragment extends ListFragment{
private DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
ArrayAdapter<Event> adapter;

List<Event> eventsList = new ArrayList<Event>();
Event[] events = {
        new Event(...), //Test data
        new Event(...),
        new Event(...)
};

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false); //Custom view
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    adapter = new EventsAdapter(getActivity(), events);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    database.child("Events").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot s : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Event event = s.getValue(Event.class);
                eventsList.add(event);
                //adapter.add(event); crashes the app for some reason
            }
            events = eventsList.toArray(new Event[eventsList.size()]);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}

public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {...}
}
```

I'm not able to find what's wrong in the code, how can I fix this?

Comment: `crashes the app for some reason` with an exception and a stacktrace, which you have to show.

Comment: @KuroMajutsu: pls, don't put your answer in the question. leave the question as is and put your whole answer in the actual answer!

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem you need to use `ChildEventListener` in stead of `addValueEventListener`.

```
database.child("Events").addChildEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot s : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
             Event event = s.getValue(Event.class);
             eventsList.add(event);
             //adapter.add(event); crashes the app for some reason
        }
        events = eventsList.toArray(new Event[eventsList.size()]);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use arrays when you expect to modify your data, use ArrayLists.

Comment: pls, put your complete answer here. that is what the answer post is for.